# Why do I keep getting this DeactivateSystemExtension popup on macOS Monterey 12.4?

Tags: macos, virus

I upgraded to macOS Monterey 12.4 yesterday and today I keep getting this "DeactivateSystemExtension" message, asking me for my login credentials. Not knowing what this is I cancel it, thinking I might have some kind of malware or virus. However, it keeps coming back.

A Google search really doesn't pull up anything, except some reference to MacAfee, which I have never installed.

I've scanned my system for viruses using the free version of Antivirus One (by Trend Micro) from the Mac App Store, but found nothing.

Does anyone know what this is?

[image]

I also have observed that my Jabra headset software is now showing the following error message:

[image]

It appears that these two issues may be related, but I cannot say for sure. I can confirm, however, that the Jabra software was now reporting this issue before upgrading to macOS 12.4.

Comment: Dpes the output of  `systemextensionsctl list` shed some light on the origin of the extension?

Answer (score 0):

**System Extensions** are Apple's replacement for **kernel extensions**.  They're used for things like VPNs and security agents, file synch utilities such as Dropbox, virtualization tools like VMware or Parallels - [here's Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210999)

Did you upgrade to Monterey 12.4 from an earlier release, or directly from macOS Big Sur?  What third-party applications do you have installed?  If you open System Preferences > Extensions, are there any items you don't recognize or recall installing?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error, and I also have Jabra software. That's the error. In the Jabra update software window it separately said I needed to say OK to updating it, but that there was a problem updating the system extension, so it doesn't seem to work. It'll be a bug in the jabra software that'll be patched hopefully soon, but at some point. Don't let it worry you mate.